# Problem deploying only Apollo Server to heroku

Tags: express, heroku, apollo-server

I am deploying an Apollo Server for my database to heroku and it is giving an application error. It is not simply show that there is a problem with the get route, it says that the application has an error and the error logs say that the app is crashing. It runs fine locally.

I have set up the procfile with: web: node app.js .
I have tried it with the procfile removed.
I have set playground and introspection to true. I saw that that could be the problem but it did not seem to help.
The port is set to process.env.PORT || 8080 .

Here is the minimal code:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const express = require('express');
const db = require('./models');
const typeDefs = require('./data/schema');
const resolvers = require('./data/resolvers');

const app = express();

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: { db },
  introspection: true,
  playground: true,
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is ready at ${PORT}`);
});
```

I am also using some other functions (trying to set up a cron process), but those are commented out.

I would expect to get the / get route to at least say hello, or for the /graphql route to display playground. I am getting neither of those options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to add the following to package.json:

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "app.js",
        ...
    }
```

And I needed to install packages listed in the heroku logs --tail, but I have had those errors before. Writing the script start key into the package.json file is for when you are deploying your server independently of your react (or client) side.